# How to get an IHttpContextAccessor instance (or equivalent) in a background task?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

In my ASP.Net Core 3.1 webapi, I'm registering the `IHttpContextAccessor` as a singleton and injecting it into all my controllers. I have an interface that also gets injected into all my controllers and my services (which in turn connect to the db). The implementation is:

```
public class PrincipalProvider : IPrincipalProvider
{
    private readonly UserPrincipal principal;

    public PrincipalProvider(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        accessor.HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("principal", out object principal);
        this.principal = principal as UserPrincipal;
    }

    public UserPrincipal GetPrincipal()
    {
        return principal;
    }
}
```

The ctor of a service looks like:

```
    public MyService(
        IPrincipalProvider provider,
        ILogger<MyService> logger, 
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(provider, logger, unitOfWork) 
    { }
```

All the above works as expected as long as I'm within the request context.

I have a controller action that starts a background task using the new `IHostedService` implementation with a background queue, and it gets started like this:

```
backgroundQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async (scope, hubContext, ct) =>
{
    await hubContext.Clients.Client(provider.GetPrincipal().ConnectionId).Notify();
    var myService = scope.Resolve<IMyService>();
}
```

where `scope` is `ILifetimeScope` and `hubConext` is `IHubContext<MyHub, IMyHub>`. The `provider` variable is the `IPrincipalProvider` that was injected into the controller ctor.

The problem is that when I try to resolve `IMyService` within the task, it creates an instance of `IPrincipalProvider` and that in turn requires `IHttpContextAccessor` which doesn't exist anymore.

What is the solution in this case? Do I need to have a second ctor on the service with a different `IPrincipalProvider` which gets the context from somewhere else? And if that's the case, from where?

Comment: HttpContext is created with the begining of a request and destroyed with end of response. Background tasks runs independent from HttpContext so it is not feasible to get an HttpContext in there.

Comment: Don't use IHttpContextAccessor in the background service ;)

Comment: Yes i know that. What is the alternative then? I need an alternative that enables me to inject rhe principal provider (or variant of ir) into the services' ctor with Resolve)

Comment: Is it not possible for you to resolve the IMyService outside of the function that run in the Background? So the IMyService is resolved when the HttpContextAccessor exist and the UserPrinciple is saved in the instance? And you just write var myService = theResolvedService?

Comment: @Darm I tried that by injecting `ILifetimeScope` into the ctor and then creating a child scope, and wrapping the task inside it. The problem still persists because the DbContext gets disposed of too.

Comment: You'd extract data out of HTTP context and pass that to your background service. `IHttpContextAccessor` itself is a singleton so it exists long as the app lifetime. But it reads `HttpContext` from the request `Task`'s ambient data. After the request is finished, the context is also gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nicest solution would be to have 2 implementations of `IPrincipalProvider`, the one that use the `httpContextAccessor` and another one that use something else. Unfortunately it is not always easy to have the other implementation.

When you create the child lifetimeScope you can add registration to this child lifetime scope. You can register a `StaticPrincipalProvider` here.

```
 private async Task BackgroundProcessing(...) {
    ... 
    try {
        using(ILifetimeScope queueScope = this._rootScope.BeginLifetimeScope(builder => {
            builder.RegisterInstance(new StaticPrincipalProvider(principal))
                   .As<IPrincipalProvider>();
        })){
            await workItem(queueScope, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
    ...
 }
```

All you have to do now is to find a way to get the corresponding principal when you dequeue the task. To do this you can change the implementation of `BackgroundTaskQueue` to use a `ConcurrentQueue<WorkItem>` instead of `ConcurrentQueue<Func<ILifetimeScope, CancellationToken, Task>>` where `WorkItem` is

```
public class WorkItem {
    public Func<ILifetimeScope, CancellationToken, Task> Work { get; private set; }
    public IPrincipal Principal { get; private set; }
    // or
    public Action<ContainerBuilder> builderAccessor { get; private set; }
}
```

and because `BackgroundTaskQueue` is instanciated with a request scope you will have access to the current principal.

Comment: How is the work item instantiated with the queueScope?

Comment: I've added the current code on Github: https://github.com/cryo75/BackgroundQueue

Comment: because it's a *data* object and not a service you can instantiate it with the C# `new` keyword. There is many place where to create it, for example in the `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` method of your `BackgroundTaskQueue`.

Comment: I still don't get how queueScope is being passed. The only way is to change the `Work` property to `Func<ILifetimeScope, CancellationToken, Task> Work { get; }`

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono sorry it was a wrong copy/paste. The func should still have the lifetimescope

Comment: And then it changes to `await workItem.Work(queueScope, stoppingToken);`? correct?

Comment: I got it working to a certain extent. However, the problem is with the scope because it's using the one from the controller's ctor and not the child scope.